# Enable Hebrew Swipe Input

Tags: keyboard, swype, hebrew

I noticed I can use (with my out of the box Nexus 4) swipe for.input in English but there does not seem to be a way to use swipe for Hebrew input.
Am I missing a configuration option that enable this?
I know there are 3rd party applications that does Hebrew swipe input but I prefer not to use them if the OS provides me that functionality.

Comment: Today (almost a year after my initial post) I tried using swipe on the Hebrew keyboard and now it works.

Answer (score 4):

Did you activate the Hebrew language pack in the Settings/Language & Input/Android Keyboard Settings/Input Languages? Hebrew is listed there. Check the box.

I don't know if that will give support for swiping but it will at least add the language dictionary.

Comment: Yes, Hebrew is activated. I can write (Hebrew keyboard) in Hebrew just not using swipe.

Comment: You may have to go with a 3rd party app like Swype Beta SwiftKey to get Hebrew swiping. I believe Swype supports Hebrew. Not sure about SwiftKey.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: uninstall your current google keyboard (it will ask you if you're sure you want to uninstall updates as you can't really uninstall the keyboard), then reinstall it.

If you're having trouble finding it in the play store here's a link to open from your phone:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin

Comment: Tried it but that did not work for me.

Comment: This worked for me. I didn't have gesture support for Croatian. After reinstalling, when I switched to the Croatian language, a toast message applied saying something like "Downloading, gestures will be soon available for Croatian". It sucks that there's no way to trigger this manually.